# mobile-safari javascript: multiple setTimeouts or setIntervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari

i am doing some animations with javascript on iOs and mobile-safari using setTimeout.

it seems though that when i have two timeouts defined at the same time, the shorter one doesnt get executed until the longer one gets.

```
setTimeout(a, 1000);
setTimeout(b, 300);

//it seems that both a and b will be called after 1000ms.
```

the same seems to happen with setInterval

is that a known issue?
if yes, is there a workaround?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way it should happen... I suspect you may a problem elsewhere.

Try this test in some different browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/V6Ktd/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="timetest()">Test</a>
<div>First fired at <span id="resultA"></span></div>
<div>First fired at <span id="resultB"></span></div>
```

JS:

```
function timetest() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("resultA").innerText = "a:" + new Date().getTime();
     }, 1000);
     setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("resultB").innerText = "b:" + new Date().getTime();
     }, 30);
}
```

In Chrome after clicking test I see:

```
First fired at a:1302168904051
First fired at b:1302168903081
```

I see similar results in Mobile Safari.